# Fast lookup from floating point index into array

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, floating-point, indices

Suppose I have `n` intervals of length `len` on an axis. Each of them is assigned a value in an `ndarray`. Now I'd like to look-up some values at positions `query_pos` given as floating point numbers. Currently, I plan to do it the following way:

```
n = 100
len = 0.39483
data = ... # creates ndarray with data of length n = 100
query_pos = ... # creates an ndarray with positions to query
values_at_query_pos = data[(query_pos / len).astype(int)] # questionable line
```

**Is that a good way to do it or are there more efficient ways to convert a floating point query position into an integer index and then read from an array?** I particularly wonder, wether `astype(int)` is a cheap or an expensive operation, compared for example to the division or the memory read.

Some more remarks:

- Finally, it will be used in 2 and 3 dimensions. Currently, I plan to
  catch positions that would lead to illegal indices *before* they go
  into the lookup stage.
- The `data` array will have a high-enough resolution so that I don't
  need any filtering or interpolation. That will be done in previous
  stages.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of dividing each element of `query_pos` by that scalar, we can pre-calculate the reciprocal of the scalar and use multiplication instead for some speedup there. The intuition is that division is a more costly affair than multiplication.

Here's a quick runtime test on it -

```
In [177]: # Setup inputs
     ...: n = 100
     ...: len1 = 0.39483
     ...: data = np.random.rand(100)
     ...: query_pos = np.random.randint(0,25,(100000))
     ...: 

In [178]: %timeit query_pos / len1
1000 loops, best of 3: 612 µs per loop

In [179]: %timeit query_pos * (1/len1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 173 µs per loop
```

Secondly, if there are many repeated indices, just like in the setup used for the runtime test shown earlier, we can use [`np.take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) for some further marginal improvement, as shown below -

```
In [196]: %timeit data[(query_pos *(1/len1)).astype(int)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 538 µs per loop

In [197]: %timeit np.take(data,(query_pos * (1/len1)).astype(int))
1000 loops, best of 3: 526 µs per loop
```

If you are planning to use it on generic ndarrays, we would need to use `axis` param with `np.take`.

Comparing it with the original approach -

```
In [202]: %timeit data[(query_pos / len1).astype(int)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 967 µs per loop
```

Finally, on the question of how the division operation stacks up against converting to `int`, they seem comparable on the big dataset. But, it seems you can't avoid the conversion as needed for indexing. Here's a timing test on it -

```
In [210]: idx = query_pos * (1/len1)

In [211]: %timeit query_pos * (1/len1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 165 µs per loop

In [212]: %timeit idx.astype(int)
10000 loops, best of 3: 110 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can output the result of the division straight to an `int` array:

```
idx = np.empty_like(query_pos, int)
np.divide(query_pos, len, out=idx, casting='unsafe')
```

This will be noticeably faster only for large arrays. But this code is harder to read, so only optimize if it's a bottleneck!